# Custom XML Generator UI from XSD

Tags: xml, user-interface, xsd, xml-generation

I have an XSD document. My requirement is to create a UI which will generate an XML based on some input fields values and rules in XSD document.

Are there any tools available online, that will take the XSD document and create a UI with input elements for each node in xsd and generating the custom XML based on XSD?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks,
Hareesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274615/get-html-form-from-xsd/8359238#8359238). What's not clear, for sure, is what kind of UI do you want generated and maintained; the post I refer to covers a wide range of scenarios, even though the question was specific to HTML.

The twist may be that these days, rules in XSD, particularly if you start thinking about XSD 1.1, have a whole new meaning. It that is what you had in mind, while co-constraints may still be easy to add, conditional type assignments are not. Regardless, XSD 1.1 is a long way from having any significant adoption, if only because of limited availability of fully compliant and free processors.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The post your referred clearly states my requirement. I will explore that and get back to you if I have further questions :)