# Dynamically Generate A Form Using an XSD file?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a Java file that has XML annotations and I have an XSD file related to it. I want to generate a form at web page using that XSD file (dynamically). If a field is required I will put a mark at form field that shows it is a required field. User will fill fields. I will save it as an XML file and I will validate it against my XSD file. If a non valid situation occurs I will show it to user.

What can I use to achieve my purpose. What do you suggest for my architecture?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274615/get-html-form-from-xsd